# Sharing .Net types in a wcf service with a no .Net client

Tags: c#, wcf

I develop a `webservice` in WCF returning a `dataset`.

When I create my .Net test app to consume the WCF I can receive the `dataset` and assign it to a `datagrid` without any problem. Visual Studio does all the job for me.

But when my partner is trying to consume the WCF in c++ he told me he processes the data as a XML and does the parsing as a string.

I guess there should exist a better way he consumes my data. 
But because I'm not familiar with c++, don't know how should that work. 
Should I create a class for my `Dataset` row and return a `MyClass` array instead?

Now, on the other hand if I want receive a Dataset from him? 
 
How will he create the XML? 
 
Or should I receive a XML string instead and do the parsing on my side?

EDIT: Just in case c++ is under Linux.

Comment: You Should try Complex types for returning data

Comment: Use a [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to encapsulate the data - that way you preserve the interoperability functionality of web services.  Using built-in .NET data types will break that interoperability, as you and your partner have found out.

Comment: Ok, I read DataContract and look easy. But how my partner will Deserialize and Serialize in c++ ?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx

Comment: Your partner should generate the serialization/deserialization code from the WSDL that .net will generate.

Answer (score 2):

The [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a .Net data type that won't have a specific analogue in non .Net languages. If the C++  consumer is using .Net, then in theory the DataSet should be deserializable.

For an API, you generally want to use simple custom objects and collection types that can be serialized as an array. For example, if your DataSet has a schema that contains

```
Column1    int
Column2    string
Column3    bool
```

and do forth, then you could create a custom class to represent that:

```
public class YourObjectType 
{
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public bool Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

And store your DataSet contents in an appropriate collection object. If sorting is important, then convert to a `Queue<YourObjectType>`, otherwise `List<YourObjectType>` is generally the best approach. Both of these types serialize to an array. You can iterate across the rows in the dataset to create one object per row and then place that object in the new collection.

As a further tip: for a performance boost, look into getting rid of the DataSet altogether. If you are pulling from a database, it will be better to get a DataReader instead of a DataSet, and then map the contents of that DataReader directly into the new object type and collection. DataSets are computationally expensive compared to directly reading database data.

Comment: I had a program that was bulk inserting data into a database using a DataSet that was performing badly. My profiler revealed that the DataSet, not the CSV parser nor the database itself, was the bottleneck.

Comment: Once you follow sufqua's advice, you can use wsdl2h to build C++ header files. http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html

Comment: @JonathanAllen When you use wsdl2h and include the headers, can you create objects from myClass in C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider exposing a REST endpoint (via WCF or WebAPI) instead of a Web Services/SOAP endpoint. Then your C++ developer can use the C++ REST SDK to build his client.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342869.aspx

More info: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/A-Cpp-REST-SDK-OSS-web-services-on-Windows-and-Linux

Comment: This sound good, but because I dont work with c++, looks like is limited to windows?  My partner work under linux. Sorry for not include that info in the question.